# Should I edit an answer to a previous version of a question which no longer applies?

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer, old-questions

I asked this [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6322364/627517) about the use of `std::shared_ptr` in C++ code but incorrectly specified a major detail in the example code. Once I changed the question, the highest-voted answer (which said that I shouldn't have the problem I was having) no longer applies. Someone else has answered the new version of the question very well and I marked it as the answer. But the answer that no longer applies still has more votes. What should I do so it doesn't confuse or mislead those that visit the question in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would not edit the high-voted answer, but rather leave a comment on the high-voted answer explaining that your edit invalidated the answer.  I would also leave a comment on the accepted answer explaining why that answer was accepted and not the high-voted answer.